# How to convert a String to a list of ascii values with map in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, linked-list, mapreduce, ascii

I am taking a course on functional programming at the university and I am trying to solve a problem for an assignment. I have implemented a `LinkedList` in Scala and one of the functions I have implemented for that list is `map` if the following signature:

```
override def map(mapFunc: Int => Int): IntList
```

Now I have to write a function called **encode** which uses this map function in order to convert a String to a list of ASCII values of each character. For instance:

`"abcdef"` should return: `SinglyLinkedIntList(97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102)`

My attemp so far is:

```
def encode(s: String): IntList = {
    var a = "abcdef".map(_.toByte)
}
```

But this just converts the string to an Array. I am not sure how to continue from here. Could anyone help me understand how a problem like this could be solved using functional principles? Thanks in advance

Comment: depending on the constructor you have for `SinglyLinkedIntList`, you can do `SinglyLinkedIntList(s.map(_.toByte).toList)`

Comment: `"abcdef".map(...` invokes the `map()` method attached to a `String` instance. You have to convert `s` to an instance of your `LinkedList`. Then when you call `.map()` on it you'll get the correct one.

Comment: and get rid of that var

Comment: The map signature must be implicitly declared. `def map[A, B](mapFunc: A => B): IntList `